# How to properly connect ROR with Oracle database with Ruby-OCI8 gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I'm trying to use Oracle Database Xe on my ruby on rails app
but I'm having a lot of trouble with my database connection I'm currently not sure what the problem is, but according to what I have read I may have a problem with my TNS setup the error message that I'am having is

`OCIError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

The error appears every time I try to run rake db:migrate

on my rails console I try to run `OCI8.new` and it gives me this error

`OCIError: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

I'm pretty much stuck and I'm really not sure what to do here.

TNS:

`METRO=
 (description=
   (address_list=
     (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = 127.0.0.1)(port = 1521))
   )
 (connect_data =
   (service_name=METRO)
 )
)`

Database.yml :

`development:
    adapter: oracle_enhanced
    database: metro
    host: 192.168.18.55
    username: metro
    password: imperium`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the port in database.yml file.

```
    development:
      adapter: oracle_enhanced
      host: localhost
      port: 1521
      database: xe
      username: user
      password: secret
```